# Travel to England before a possible move in the future

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, weddings

I have a few questions so bare with me.  I've found my soulmate in England. I'm waiting on my passport to get here. Then I am going. We are planning on getting married. From what I gather I can stay for 6 months.  Then I have to return.  How long do I need to stay back here i  the USA before I return.  Second question; Is there any specific paperwork I need. Or can I just buy a one way ticket And return at the end of 6 month??, Shedding any light on this would help loads.. Thanx

Comment: Questions about moving permanently to another country are better suited to [Expatriates.SE].  However, questions about entering on a six-month-or-less visitor visa *are* on topic here.

Comment: You need a special visa to get married in the UK and to officially register your intention to do so.

Comment: To those voting to close: The title suggests an expats question, but the body is actually about a short-term visit: "From what I gather I can stay for 6 months. Then I have to return. How long do I need to stay back here i the USA before I return."  I have voted to reopen.

Comment: What you want to do **is** possible, but if you show up at the border and tell them what you just told us, you **will** be turned back. (Getting married is a breach of your visitor terms for a start). You need to do some serious, careful planning before going ahead with this kind of thing. At the very least, familiarize yourself with some of the questions we have here of US citizens being turned back at the border, and read the visitor rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules and https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa/overview

Comment: On a personal note, I'd mention that if you've never even held a passport before, you might seriously underestimate the cultural differences involved in such a relationship. Even between seemingly similar cultures like the UK and US, there are some important differences in values and norms. These obviously don't prevent a successful relationship, but you need to understand them if you're going to have such a relationship. Don't rush things with so much untested ground, and potentially such a precarious position if things do go wrong.

Comment: @pnuts the short-term work/study qs always get reopened I think. We have a meta, where we came to some degree of agreement of what counted as travel, and that work/study was not the defining line. However, I'd argue this is an expats question, on the grounds of the X-Y problem. Yes, the original Q is about visa-free stays as a visitor - but it's pretty clear they intend to use that to live in the UK. THat is going to get them in trouble. Instead, what is realy being asked is about how to move to the UK properly. That's an expats question.

Comment: If you have not met your soul-mate in person, in real-life, then consider visiting instead.

Comment: @GayotFow from the profile picture, I infer that they have met in person, though of course it is not very strong evidence; it could be a picture of two completely different people.

Answer (score 7):

There's no hard-and-fast rule about how long you need to stay away before you can re=enter, but as soon as the proportion of your time spent in the country begins to approach 50%, you can expect a good deal more scrutiny.  Therefore, using visitor visas, your best case scenario will be to alternate periods of six months in and six months out.  The likelihood of being able to do this for more than a couple of visits is pretty small, however, and you may even have trouble entering for your first visit.

Once you are married, however, you may be eligible to get a spouse visa allowing you to move to the UK.  These are costly and difficult to qualify for.  If your future spouse is a citizen of another EU country (not the UK), then you can get an EEA family permit, which is considerably easier.

That's off-topic for this site, however, and you should ask about it on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) if you are interested in learning more.  When you do that, mention your soulmate's citizenship.  The rest of this answer discusses your plan to go to the UK as soon as your passport arrives.

If you're traveling to the UK to get married, or even to see your fiancee, you will be suspected of intending to immigrate, which is not allowed when you enter with your visa-free six-month leave to enter.  There's therefore a risk that you will be turned away at the border.  If you plan to get married on any given trip, in fact, you need a visa for that trip.

You *are* allowed simply to visit your future spouse on a visitor visa, but you will have a hard time proving, as you must, that you intend to leave the country within six months.  If you arrive with a one-way ticket, for example, you'll need to show that you have ample funds to support yourself without working, and that you'll still have enough money at the end of six months to buy a one-way ticket back home.

As evidence that you intend to return to the US, the officials in the UK will want to see evidence of your job and home in the US.  It sounds like you plan to abandon these, so that will definitely not work in your favor.

Fortunately for you, unlike most of Europe, visa-exempt nationals such as you *can* apply for a visa before visiting the UK.  This allows you to have your plans evaluated before you travel, rather than after you arrive at the border.  If you're rejected, the consequences are far less burdensome, since you will not essentially have thrown away a plane ticket.

A word of advice: Read up on [UK visas](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration).  Especially, have a look at

- [Standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa)
- [Marriage visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa)
- [Family of a settled person visa](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk)

Then make a long-term plan that will allow you to realize your dreams with your soulmate.  An impetuous journey to the UK border is likely to lead to disappointment for both of you.